# If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ ,why does $|Ha|=|H|=|aH|$ for all $a\in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Proof in the book notes:$Ha \rightarrow H$ is a bijection.
END

I think there may exist $x,y \in H$ such that $xa=ya= \alpha \in H$,then $xa \rightarrow \alpha ,ya \rightarrow \alpha$
it become a surjection.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: $\tilde{a}:G\rightarrow G, x\mapsto ax$ is an isomorphism for every $a\in G$. Then restrict to $H$ and see what happens

Comment: x->ax is an isomorphism. why?

Comment: Not isomorphism, but bijection. The inverse map of multiplication by $a$ is multiplication by $a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will elaborate on this bijection.  Indeed fix an element $a\in G$, and associate the map,

$$\varphi_a: H\longrightarrow aH $$ given by $$\varphi_a(h)=ah $$

I will show this is a bijection between $H$ and $aH$.  First, it is easy to see this map is surjective (onto).  Take $x\in aH$, then $x=ah$ for some $h\in H$ by definition. So we have $\varphi_a(h)=x$.  Thus our map is surjective.

Now I will show the map is injective (one to one).  Let $\varphi_a(h_1)=\varphi_a(h_2)$.  This implies that $ah_1=ah_2$.  But in $G$ the element $a$ has an inverse, so we see that,

$$a^{-1}(ah_1)=a^{-1}(ah_2)\Rightarrow h_1=h_2 $$

Therefore, $\varphi_a(h_1)=\varphi_a(h_2)\Rightarrow h_1=h_2$.  So our map is injective.  Therefore, since we have that $H$ and $aH$ are in one to one correspondence, we have $|H|=|aH|$.  $a$ was arbitrary so this argument holds for each $a$ in the group.  The same reasoning applies for multiplication by $a$ on the right.  I hope this elaboration was helpful!